# How do you handle Performance tasks in Agile?

Tags: agile, performance

How is the Agile process affected if a stakeholder requests that a specific operation in the software need to perform better?  This could mean that it runs very slow for a customer's needs (even with hardware improvements) or it crashes completely under the demand.

How would this affect different parts of the Agile process, including:

1. **User/Technical Stories**.  Are the User Stories limited to "As an end user, I would like part of the software to perform better."?
2. **Acceptance Criteria**.  What kind of goals should be pursued?
3. **Spikes**.  Should a developer research that part of the software to try to identify areas of improvement?
4. **Sprint Demos**.  What is the best way to share performance improvements with the stakeholders?

In addition to any other parts of the process that might be treated differently under this request.

Comment: Better performance is a requirement like anything else (ok, its a nonfunctional one, but that is not a big difference). The fact you asked this question makes gives me the impression you think it should be handled differently than other requirements. Why?

Comment: @DocBrown, that's a good question.  I guess because the requirements are more abstract, that makes it harder to establish Acceptance Criteria.  But there's also the question of how proactively we should be requiring performance checking on all other user stories.

Comment: If the client doesn't like the performance, that means they don't consider the user story as completed. After awhile, you can probably guess what they're going to accept throughout the project and they'll start telling you as well.

Comment: Performance is a well-measurable requirement, all you need is a clock. So it should not be too hard to define acceptance criteria.

Comment: @DocBrown - Is that reasonable though?  Complex operations are going to take a certain amount of time no matter how well the code is structured.  Is it better to aim for a specific time threshold or to aim for a percentage, like 50% faster?

Comment: @JeffO - It may have been considered Completed for one client in the past, but then when a client with a significantly more massive business demand tries the same software, it does not run adequately.

Comment: You and the client/stakeholders should agree on several points of performance at load, for a given system configuration, as well as the engineering budget they're willing to provide to reach those points.  Usually there's some low hanging fruit to be had, but then after that it takes real work to improve.  If the project is highly experimental (as agile projects sometimes are), it may not be worth putting the engineering in until business requirements and feature set are more stable.

Comment: @HarlanWescott: 50% faster can be measured using a clock.

Comment: Treat it as a bug that just happened to be discovered at a late stage. (I am not convinced of the "Agile" methodology, so I would say, let its adherents figure out how to fit this into its plumbing.)

Comment: @HarlanWescott - then you just have a new user story and you're right back where you started.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few different ways that you can handle performance (and, really, any non-functional requirements).

If the requirement is known early in the development, make it part of your acceptance criteria or Definition of Done and make sure it stays there. If you have a specific performance requirement, develop tests (preferably automated tests) to ensure that you are hitting the performance metrics. If it's a specific reliability requirement, develop some tests that you can run on a regular are harder to do this with because it's harder to test for them in an automated fashion. Usability requirements that state a particular user class must be able to perform a function in a given period of time, for example. Testability and modifiability requirements are also harder to test, but can be analyzed.

If you are making a change to the system, treat it like a user story. This is perfectly valid for new stories as well as instances where functionality has been delivered, but needs to be improved. "As a {user class}, I want to {function} in {time}" is a valid user story, as would similar stories. It's important to make your requirements specific and measurable, though, so you know when you have achieved them. You can prioritize them in the product backlog, estimate them, and pull them into the iteration just like any other story.

Once implemented, you can share the results of your testing at the Sprint Demo, just like any other story. If your requirements are harder to demonstrate (for example, certain up-time), then you can use your test results. Other attributes can be demonstrated, either through using the software or scripts that can drive the functionality.

If you need to, you can use a Spike to address these stories or requirements. If you need to do research first, then starting a timeboxed a Spike is the appropriate thing to do. This is useful when you don't know if achieving a particular requirement is feasible or there is insufficient information to estimate and implement. You may not actually solve the issue in the Spike, but you can at least commit to understanding the issue after a period of time and having a conversation with the stakeholder.

Comment: Thanks Thomas.  I'm trying to determine if it's really reasonable to have user stories that are based on specific time thresholds.  In some cases, this may be below the time that is possible for an operation given the best hardware and software architecture.  I'm wondering if it's better instead to aim for a specific percentage goal based on user experience.  For example, "I want a form to load 50% faster than current times." instead of "I want a form to load in under 5 seconds."

Comment: @HarlanWescott Both are potentially valid requirements. However, if it is technically impossible to achieve one of them, then that's a conversation between the development team and the stakeholders. Preferably, it's one backed by data that shows it's impossible.

Comment: You should not worry too much about not being able to meet the performance request. If you are not sure it can be done, make sure the user story does not promise too much. You will be giving it a try to make it better and you will get back at the stakehokder soon to check if it works for him. That is the point of working agile, the point is not to cover your but upfront or to make sure whatever is on the sticky notes will be delivered.